# Middle align text with Font Awesome icons

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I want to middle align text with Font Awesome icons - using inline style.

But, this does not work. Could anyone help please?

```
<div>
    <span style="font-size: 17px !important; font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif; color: #000000;">Rent single videos for $1.00 with Credit Card, Bitcoin or PayPal</span> 
    <span class="fa fa-cc-mastercard  fa-3x" style=" vertical-align: middle;"></span> 
    <span class="fa fa-cc-visa fa-3x" style=" vertical-align: middle;"></span> 
    <span class="fa fa-btc fa-3x" style=" vertical-align: middle;"></span> 
    <span class="fa fa-cc-paypal fa-3x" style=" vertical-align: middle;"></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: No idea what the visual outcome you are trying achieve here is? Maybe post an image of what you are wanting it to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work, regardless of font-size of your text, you need to add `vertical-align: middle;` to first span too:

```
<div>
    <span style="font-size: 17px !important; font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif; color: #000000; vertical-align: middle;">Rent single videos for $1.00 with Credit Card, Bitcoin or PayPal</span> 
    <span class="fa fa-cc-mastercard  fa-3x" style=" vertical-align: middle;"></span> 
    <span class="fa fa-cc-visa fa-3x" style=" vertical-align: middle;"></span> 
    <span class="fa fa-btc fa-3x" style=" vertical-align: middle;"></span> 
    <span class="fa fa-cc-paypal fa-3x" style=" vertical-align: middle;"></span> 
</div>
```